# Enum named `Type` in nested class fails

Tags: swift, enums

For some reason, having a nested class with an nested enum named `Type` dosen't play well with the swift compiler.

```
class A {

    class B {

        enum Type {
            case One
            case Two
        }

        let myC: Type

        init(myC: Type) {
            self.myC = myC
        }

    }

    func getB(myC: B.Type) -> B {
        return B(myC: myC) // ERROR 1
    }

}

let a = A()
let b = a.getB(.Two) // ERROR 2
```

The above code produces two errors: `'A.B.Type' is not convertible to 'A.B.Type'` and `'A.B.Type.Type' does not have a member named 'Two'`.

The following cases does work:

- `class B` outside of `class A`
- `let b = A.B(myC: .Two)`
- `enum C` instead of `enum Type`

It this a bug in Swift or **is this intended behaviour?** Is `Type` a reserved name which we shouldn't use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

B.Type refers to class B's metatype, which is why the compiler doesn't like you defining an inner-enum with the name 'Type'.

You can use `Type` in variable/constant declaration to do class reflection:

```
class A {

    required init() {}
}

class B {
    var a: A.Type
    var aInstance: A

    init() {
        a = A.self
        aInstance = a()
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! No Enums named `Type` for me then, even in non-nested classes

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I keep pulling my hair why my nested enum keep unusable!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's a reserved word. But you can go right ahead and use a reserved word as long as you mark it in backticks. This works fine:

```
class A {
    class B {
        enum Type {
            case One
            case Two
        }
        let myC: `Type`
        init(myC: `Type`) {
            self.myC = myC
        }
    }
    func getB(myC: B.`Type`) -> B {
        return B(myC: myC)
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree completely! :)

Comment: This is not problem of using reserved word as identifier. You can use `Type` identifier for your enum without backticks because it is outside the context in which it appear in the grammar. Even if you go with backticks, the problem is elsewhere. The problem is both `B.Type`  and `B.\`Type\`` will refer to B's metatype, not to inner `Type`. This is how it works for me in Swift 2.