# Access enum value defined in another class

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, enums

I have a enum defined as follow,

```
class Question: NSObject {
    enum Type:String {
        case Text = "TEXT"
        case Image = "IMAGE"
    }
    /**!!!Here I can access it like this!!!*/
    var type = Type.Text
}
```

However, in another class,

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    /**!!!This doesn't work!!!*/
    var type = Question.Type.Text
}
```

Are there anything that I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know exactly why but you can't name your enum `Type`. Change it to something else and it will work.

Comment: Looks like you reimplement existing type `Type`, try to use `enum Type2:String` for example to test it

Comment: Here's an explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608936/enum-named-type-in-nested-class-fails

Comment: @Rog Thanks, finally got it. Apple is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the aforementioned stuff (rename your enum!), you simply have to declare the enum outside of your `Question` class. You don't have to make a new file for this (although you can if you want), simply put it above your class like so:

```
enum QuestionType: String {
    case Text  = "TEXT"
    case Image = "IMAGE"
}

class Question: NSObject {
    //...
}
```

Now you can use the `QuestionType` enum in your `MyViewController` class.